# Event delegation on page load function

Tags: jquery, events, delegation

i am hoping someone can assist. I am using a jQuery plugin called pinterest_grip to display content on my site stacked like it does on pinterest.

Here is the code that initializes it:

```js
$("#blog-landing").pinterest_grid({
  no_columns: 4,
  padding_x: 35,
  padding_y: 15,
  margin_bottom: 150,
  single_column_breakpoint: 320
});
```

I load content into my page with ajax, the following sample code gets pulled in:

```html
<section id="blog-landing">
    <!-- stuff -->
</section>
```

The problem is that when I load it directly onto the page, it works perfectly, but when loading via ajax, the function does not work. I have done some research and found that I basically need to turn to event delegation to achieve the task, I have implemented event delegation on click events before, but this function should fire on load. How can I achieve this with this function?

Thanks in advance